# JavaScript Wrapper Function - inner function not invoked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to invoke inner function after wrapping all codes of javascript file in outer function, but my inner function is not getting invoked.

Below is my javascript:

```
(function(){

function calculateArea(){

    var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("sideA").value); 
    var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("sideB").value); 
    var c=parseInt(document.getElementById("sideC").value); 

    debugger;

    var perBy2= (a+b+c)/2;  

    var squareArea=  perBy2 * ( perBy2-a)*( perBy2-b)*( perBy2-c);

    var areaOf=Math.sqrt(squareArea);

    document.getElementById("area").innerHTML=areaOf;


}
})();
```

Below is my html file snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
    Side A : <input type="text" id=sideA placeholder="Side A"  required /><br>
    Side B :<input type="text" id=sideB placeholder="Side B" required /><br>
    Side C :<input type="text" id=sideC placeholder="Side B" required /><br>
    <button onClick="calculateArea()">Calculate the Area</button>
    </form>

    AREA IS:<div id="area"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/area.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi all issue resolved after I removed inline event handling and added a event listner as per suggestion in my IIFE. However , I am unable to see result because values are restting and one unwanted GET call is happening.

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9999
Request URL:http://localhost:9999/JavaScriptQuestion/?
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=5CC7F1D56201D4DEB07FB6C56FF89125
Host:localhost:9999
Referer:http://localhost:9999/JavaScriptQuestion/?
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:571
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Wed, 02 Jul 2014 05:20:20 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: Your function is bound to the scope of the `immediate` function (rather than global). A quick, easy fix is to assign the callback to the global scope directly, by using `window.calculateArea = function`. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HFUvC/

Comment: What's with the `debugger` line in there?

Comment: I had just added it to see weather my code execution is going inside the function or not.

Comment: Owwait, that's actually a breakpoint o.O Didn't know that was possible :P

Comment: Using "window.calculateArea = function"  would again put my function in global scope or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner function is wrapped in the [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), so it's not in the global scope and therefore can't be called by an inline click handler, like you have on your `<button>`.

Either move the function into the global scope, or assign the click handler in the JavaScript itself, instead of inline HTML.

```
(function(){
    function calculateArea(){
        var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("sideA").value); 
        var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("sideB").value); 
        var c=parseInt(document.getElementById("sideC").value); 

        debugger;

        var perBy2= (a+b+c)/2;  
        var squareArea=  perBy2 * ( perBy2-a)*( perBy2-b)*( perBy2-c);
        var areaOf=Math.sqrt(squareArea);

        document.getElementById("area").innerHTML=areaOf;
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        // give the button an ID, or use some other way to grab it
        document.getElementById("someid").onclick = calculateArea;
    };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. How could I achieve "assigning the click handler in the JavaScript itself, instead of inline HTML."

Comment: @user3440629 see example in the answer using `window.onload` and `element.onclick`.

Comment: Ohh thanks. SO I have to remove this inline click even handler from button and apply click handler on window.onload

Comment: Yes. You can omit the `window.onload` wrapper if your code is executed after the element is rendered (for example before the closing body tag).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the (ab)use of inline event handlers, e.g.:

```
onClick="calculateArea()"
```

With inline event handlers (which are obsolete, and should not be used) you can only call methods that are in the global scope.  Your use of an IIFE wrapper has hidden your intended function from that scope.

Add an ID to your button, and add this inside the IIFE:

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', calculateArea, false);
```

Pay attention to the order in which your DOM is loaded and scripts executed, to ensure that `mybutton` actually exists at the time this line is executed.